# Select Records Using Relative Dates in Hive / Scala

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, hive

Is there a good way to solve this problem: Suppose I want to select records that are at least 6 months prior to the previously selected record for a given grouping.

Ie. I have:

```
Col A   Col B   Date
1       A       2015-01-01 00:00:00
1       A       2014-10-01 00:00:00
1       A       2014-05-01 00:00:00
1       A       2014-01-01 00:00:00
1       B       2014-01-01 00:00:00
2       A       2015-01-01 00:00:00
2       A       2014-10-01 00:00:00
2       A       2014-01-01 00:00:00
2       A       2013-10-01 00:00:00
```

I'd like to select only dates that are at least 6 months apart relative to the previously selected one. Ie it will return:

```
Col A   Col B   Date
1       A       2015-01-01 00:00:00
1       A       2014-05-01 00:00:00
1       B       2014-01-01 00:00:00
2       A       2015-01-01 00:00:00
2       A       2014-01-01 00:00:00
```

It is obvious to me how to do this using orderings if you wanted to select relative to the latest ones

(ie:

```
SELECT b.date, b..., a.latest_date 
FROM(
SELECT *, row_number OVER PARTITION BY Col A, Col B ORDER BY Date as row_number
FROM table1) temp
WHERE row_number = 1) a
INNER JOIN TABLE 1 b
ON KEY)
WHERE datediff(date, latestdate)/365 > 0.5
```

or so

, but I'm a little unclear how you would do this relative to each other. Is there a way to do this recursively in Hive / Scala or something?

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is a concept of windowing lag and lead concept is both hive and spark, you can achieve this task in both. Here is the code in spark.

```
val data = sc.parallelize(List(("1",       "A",       "2015-01-01 00:00:00"),
     |      | ("1",       "A",       "2014-10-01 00:00:00"),
     |      | ("1",       "A",       "2014-01-01 00:00:00"),
     |      | ("1",       "B",       "2014-01-01 00:00:00"),
     |      | ("2",       "A",       "2015-01-01 00:00:00"),
     |      | ("2",       "A",       "2014-10-01 00:00:00"),
     |      | ("2",       "A",       "2014-01-01 00:00:00"),
     |      | ("2",       "A",       "2013-10-01 00:00:00")
     |      | )).toDF("id","status","Date");


    val data2 =data.select($"id",$"status",to_date($"Date").alias(date));


import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window


import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val wSpec3 = Window.partitionBy("id","status").orderBy(desc("date"));

val data3 = data2.withColumn("diff",datediff(lag(data2("date"), 1).over(wSpec3),$"date")).filter($"diff">182.5 || $"diff".isNull);

data3.show
+---+------+----------+----+
| id|status|      date|diff|
+---+------+----------+----+
|  1|     A|2015-01-01|null|
|  1|     A|2014-01-01| 273|
|  1|     B|2014-01-01|null|
|  2|     A|2015-01-01|null|
|  2|     A|2014-01-01| 273|
+---+------+----------+----+
```

Comment: This is not quite right. If we have three dates less than six months apart (relative to each other) but the middle one is invalid the last one could be valid.

Consider:
2015-10-01
2015-06-01
2015-03-01

Last one is valid but in this function is will be invalid.